# Failed to connect to dl.google.com port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: curl, cygwin

```
$ curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x2001f130; line 1011 (connection #-5000)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.125.236.168...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x20059b98
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* 0x2001f130 is at send pipe head!
* - Conn 0 (0x20059b98) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x2001f130; line 1058 (connection #0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2404:6800:4001:c01::be...
* Connection failed
* connect to 2404:6800:4001:c01::be port 443 failed: Network is unreachable
* Failed to connect to dl.google.com port 443: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Expire cleared
**curl: (7) Failed to connect to dl.google.com port 443: Network is unreachable**
```

I'm trying to install google cloud sdk using curl from cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to download the script first and then run it through `bash`.

#### Example

```
$ curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash -O 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to dl.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.194.46.72...
* Connected to dl.google.com (173.194.46.72) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Feb 12 14:58:10 2014 GMT
*   expire date: Jun 12 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*   common name: *.google.com
*   issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0> GET /dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: dl.google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 3622
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Etag: "408a0"
< Expires: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 23:07:53 PST
< Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 19:48:00 GMT
< Server: downloads
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 07:07:53 GMT
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
< 
{ [data not shown]
100  3622  100  3622    0     0   8320      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8307
* Connection #0 to host dl.google.com left intact
```

Once it's finished downloading you should have a file like this:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 3622 Feb 27 02:07 install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
```

From here you can run it manually:

```
$ bash install_google_cloud_sdk.bash 
curl -f "https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz" > "/tmp/tmp.dlj5Kju8Tp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  364k  100  364k    0     0   521k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  521k

Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) (/home/saml): 
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use curl at all?  E.g. `curl google.com`.

This would happen if you're in an environment like the University of York, where you're required to use the university proxy server, and direct connections are blocked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197904/how-do-i-use-cygwin-behind-the-corporate-firewall

Technically the "network is unreachable" error happens afterwards, when curl desperately tries falling back to IPv6.  The original error is "Connection failed".